# couldn't update one field in laravel

Tags: laravel, http, put

this is the route in web.php:

```
 Route::put('/users.status', [\App\Http\Controllers\dashboard\UsersController::class, 'status'])->name('users.status');
```

and here is the code in Controller:

```
public function status(User $user) {
              try{
                $user->is_active = 1;
                $user->update();
//$user->update(['is_active' => 1 ]);
               }catch (\Exception $ex) {
                return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('status', "you couldn't update this record");
            }

            return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('status', 'User Updated successfully');
    }
```

here is the code in a view, it just a button, when click on it, I need to change the status:

```
 <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                                <form  method="POST" action="{{route('users.status', $user)}}">
                                    @csrf
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"/>
                                    <button type="submit"
                                    class="{{ $user->is_active==1 ? "bg-green-500" : "bg-red-500" }} hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-1 px-1 rounded">
                                        {{$user->is_active==1 ? "Active" : "Inactive"}}
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
```

after the button above has clicked, give me this message:

```
User Updated successfully
```

but nothing updated in database

Comment: does `$user` exist in database? did you dump and check the if it has id f.e. ?

Comment: I would try `$user->save()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First which `User` you are trying to fetch from route to controller method? You are trying to inject a `User $user` object to controller method but you did not specified a `user` param on route definition.

And on the update part; after you set `$user->is_active = 1;` you need to run `$user->save();`

So; you need to add a `user` param to your route:

```
Route::put('/users/{user}/status', [\App\Http\Controllers\dashboard\UsersController::class, 'status'])->name('users.status');
```

and run `save()` method on updated `$user` ;

```
public function status(User $user)
{
    try {
        $user->is_active = 1;
        $user->save();
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('status', "you couldn't update this record");
    }

    return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('status', 'User Updated successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `$user->save();` not `$user->update();`
Also, you can call `$user->update(['is_active'=>1]);` to have only one line of code.